# Datanucleus enhancement with Bazel

Tags: datanucleus, bazel

I'm trying to migrate Maven project to Bazel and having troubles with Datanucleus enhancement.

After `jar`-file is build, Datanucleus looks inside it and does some byte-code manipulation to enhance persistable classes. The way to perform this in Bazel is by defining a rule that takes the `*.jar` output of `java_library` rule and creates a new enhanced version of the library.

The problem that I have is that for my rule I need `datanucleus-core` package from external libraries. When I try to access it from a `genrule` by `$(location //third_party:datanucleus_core)` it point to a jar which has no classes:

```
(genrule) cmd = "echo $(location //third_party:datanucleus_core)"
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/third_party/liborg_datanucleus_datanucleus_core.jar

(genrule) cmd = "jar tf $(location //third_party:datanucleus_core)"
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

The `jar`-file resolved by Bazel in `genrule` from `$(location //third_party:datanucleus_core)` contains only `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: blaze
```

I tried to use `java_binary` rule that adds a correct `datanucleus_core.jar` into classpath, but Datanucleus enhances my libary in-place and fails to write its changes on disk (rewrite the rule's input file). Also `java_binary` rule is not supposed to be used for building.

So the question is what is the best way to enhance `jar` library in Bazel running Datanucleus utility, which is provided as a third-party dependency in Maven repository?

Bazel build label: `0.3.2-homebrew`, OS: `OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)`, java: `1.8.0_92`

**Update**

Datanucleus dependency declaration:

```
# WORKSPACE
maven_jar(
    name = "org_datanucleus_datanucleus_core",
    artifact = "org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:5.0.3",
)

# third_party/BUILD
java_library(
    name = "org_datanucleus_datanucleus_core",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = ["@org_datanucleus_datanucleus_core//jar"],
)
```

(in my question I shortened `org_datanucleus_datanucleus_core` to `datanucleus_core`)

Comment: No enhancement process will enhance classes *IN A JAR*. If that is what you're doing... You have to unpack, enhance, pack them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Neil Stockton mentioned, you cannot enhance classes in a jar.  So, the basic strategy will be:

1. Create the jar.
2. Unjar the class files.
3. Run the enhancements.
4. Jar it back up.

Steps 2 & 3 have to be rolled into 4, as Bazel insists that you declare all inputs & outputs to a build rule (and you cannot know what .class files a .java file will generate, so Bazel always jars them up).

Create a `datanucleus.bzl` file to declare your enhancement rule in.  It should look something like:

```
# Run datastore enhancements on the java_library named "jarname".
def enhance(jarname):
  # src is the name of the jar file your java_library rule generates.
  src = "lib" + jarname + ".jar"
  native.genrule(
      name = jarname + "-enhancement",
      srcs = [
          src, 
          "//third_party:datanucleus_core"
      ],
      outs = [jarname + "-enhanced.jar"],
      cmd = """
# Un-jar the .class files.
jar tf $(location {0})
# Run the enhance.
classes=""
for $$class in $$(find . -name *.class); do
  java -cp {0}:$(location //third_party:datanucleus_core) $$class
  classes="$$classes $$class"
done
# jar them back up.
jar cf $@ $$classes""".format(src),
  )
```

(I'm not too familiar with datastore so the `cmd` might need some modification, but it should be that general idea.)

Then, in your BUILD file, you'd do:

```
java_library(
    name = "my-lib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    deps = ["..."],
)

# import the rule you wrote.
load('//:datanucleus.bzl', 'enhance')
enhance("my-lib")
```

Now you can do:

```
bazel build //:my-lib-enhanced.jar
```

and use `my-lib-enhanced.jar` as a dependency in other `java_` rules.

More info on .bzl files: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/concepts.html.

---

Edited to add more info on depending on a jar:

There are a couple of options to get a jar that contains the content of datanucleus.  First, you don't need the layer of indirection: you can just say:

```
      srcs = [
          src, 
          "@datanucleus_core//jar"
      ],
```

This will give you the actual jar.

If, for some reason, you need the jar to be in third_party, you can modify third_party/BUILD to create a *deploy jar*, which is a java binary that bundles up all of its dependencies for deployment (since you're not actually going to using it as a binary, you can use whatever you want for the main class name):

```
java_binary(
    name = "datanucleus-core",
    main_class = "whatever",
    runtime_deps = ["@org_datanucleus_datanucleus_core//jar"],
)

genrule(
    name = "your-lib",
    srcs = [":datanucleus-core_deploy.jar", ...],
)
```

The `:datanucleus-core_deploy.jar` is called an *implicit target*: it's only built if requested, but it can be generated from your `java_binary` declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, @kristina. It is really useful. There is only one thing that I'm concerned about. As I mentioned in my question, I'm having troubles with accessing third-party `jar` from `genrule`. The `jar`-file returned from `$(location //third_party:datanucleus_core)` does not contain any classes, so adding it in classpath as in your example wouldn't work. It contains only `MANIFEST.MF` that says it was `Created-By: blaze`. Do you have any idea of why this happens and how I can fix it? I updated the post with my declarations of Datanucleus dependency.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include info about getting the jar in your classpath. Java library targets keep track of their dependencies, but they don't package them up (as you've seen).  Otherwise jars would get bigger and bigger as your build tree increased, so they're not included until they're "needed", e.g., in a deployment binary.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, Kristina!